# How to ensure data consistency in system with multiple databases?

Tags: data-structures, validation, consistency

Let's say, in a rather big application suite with multiple more or less integrated products, data is stored across multiple databases. Some of them are SQL-ish DB clusters, some are MongoDB clusters.

Some entities (= "rows" or "documents", depending on the type of DB) are stored in several databases. Many (if not all) entities depend on entities of another kind.

Now, the problem is: Data consistency and validation. There is a lot of data that is not in sync with other data and/or not in sync with the intended schema or the intended application logic.

Let's take an example and say the system is about pets. We have an SQL table called `pet` and a row for `dogs`. In MongoDB, there is a column for `food` containing document IDs of a collection named `petFood`. However, it could happen that:

- The document with the linked ID does not exist in `petFood` collection.
- Some `petFood` documents have no `pet` linked to them.
- The data might contradict each other, like the `dogs` row could be linked to a document with `suitableForDogs: false` property.

Additionally, there might be data consistency problems within one MongoDB document itself. E.g `MyFood` could be set both to `availableInAsia: false` and have a `distributorInAsia: ACME LTD` property (which doesn't make sense because something which is not available in Asia cannot have a distributor there`).

You may ask how come that the data has these issues. Well, there could be various reasons:

- In some situations, stuff is changed directly in DB or with an ad-hoc script instead of in the application.
- There is old data not up to date with current application logic.
- Bugs in the application code leave some data in the wrong state.
- DB migration problems happen, backup restores only work partially, and stuff like that.
- ... etc etc.

These things do happen and they will happen. Hence, manually cleaning up once and then hoping that the data will never become messy again, is pointless.

The same goes for the well-meant advice you always hear regarding MongoDB: "Enforce schema and validity on application level". It simply does not work like that.

So, the question is: What to do? I need to find a solution that makes sure that the data stays consistent and valid over time.

The best solution I could come up with

- Programmatically define all the rules that play a role regarding data consistency/validity.
- Running a regular "checker script" which checks that all the rules are followed everywhere.
- If not: The checker notifies the responsible persons like "Hey, the row `dogs` in `pet` table is assigned to a `petFood` document which has `suitableForDogs: false`. Please fix it!"
- Maybe add some kind of threshold like: A problem must appear twice in a row. (In order to exclude cases where the check happens to run during an async operation.)

But that means a lot of work and there is no technical guarantee that the people who get these notifications will react accordingly.

So, what would be a better technical approach?

(I'm not asking for organizational measurements like 'Take way database access from people notoriously and regularly messing up the data'.)

**Edit:**

Thanks for all your answers so far. I was aware that it might be a little bit too unclear what I'm asking for. I think your thoughts help me to rephrase what I'm looking for.
I know that such a problem is complex and that there are many aspects to it like financial, organizational ones etc. Some of them are off-topic here I guess.

So, what I am looking for are technical actions that a motivated dev-team could implement within, very roughly speaking, a few weeks. Either on the database layer or as an "extra" application layer or on "something in between the application and database layer".

In order to demonstrate what I was fantasizing about I'm making up something now:

> "This problem is called XY and the state-of-the-art solution is: Put a
> sample of correct data together, pass it through tool XY which will
> deduce some generic rules from the data, then set up an XY server
> which will regularly make two copies of all your databases: one copy
> for the correct data, one for the wrong data. Then you can decide from
> here what to do with them."

If there is *any* generic solution along those lines out there, then I'm not aware of it and would be thankful for any tips or even hints on what keywords to google for.

"No, something like this does not exist", would thus be an answer too.

Comment: You might want to read about the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). This says you can only pick two of Consistency Avaliability and Partition Tolerance. This makes ensuring consistency in a distributed system difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: Why do you have things strewn across multiple DBs? Why not move to a single DB (perhaps with multiple read replicas)?

Comment: @mmathis It was never purposefully designed like that but just got that way by matters outside of control of engineering team (like the acquisition of new company parts etc) and for similar reasons, re-designing everything from scratch won't happen. Maybe incrementally going to a different structure step-by-step over several years could be an option - but until that's finished, the data consistency needs to be solved anyway.

Comment: Could we focus on a specific problem and how it happens? pet-petfood broken link is more on local contraint problem to me, but the introduction is focused on heterogeneous connected databases. My comprehension is that you want to manage programaticaly replication between databases, is that the main point?

Comment: I agree, but it's hard to focus because everything is somehow connected to other problems. But yes: Consistency among heterogeneous connected databases is the main point. It's not about replication of the same data. The "pet-petfood broken link" is not "local" (in the sense of: inside one DB) since in my example "pet" is in an SQL DB, whereas "petfood" is in MongoDB.

Comment: There are entire research papers focused on this topic. This topic is not one that can be easily answered in a stackoverflow question. There are books written about this (TLDR: most of them conclude that this is a very, very difficult task and only provide strategies to mitigate the problem, not completely solve it)

Comment: FWIW, Blockchains (Bitcoin, Ethereum etc.) has IMHO the best solution to this problem: they **completely** abandon the idea of consistency. Instead they use *eventual consistency*: the idea that at any point in time all nodes cannot be consistent but at some future time they will be. What this means in practice is that past data is fully consistent but current data is not. For Bitcoin this means any transaction more than 10 minutes old are fully consistent but any transaction more recent than that cannot be trusted to be committed.

Comment: @cis The made-up example is a useful simplification, but you didn't describe your real external and internal constraints. How much money can you throw at the problem? Are losing because of the problem? Will the number of inconsistency sources grow? What inconsistencies can you live with and for how long vs which ones are no-nos? These and a number of other constraints will determine an ad-hoc ensemble of solutions - there is no magical technical recipe here.

Comment: @guillaume31 I've made some additions to my question which hopefully make clearer what I'm asking for.

Comment: @slebetman you say "There are entire research papers focused on this topic", but you don't give us one example. Same thing about "books". Can you list some of them, or, at least, give us a way to how find it?

Comment: @v1d3rm3: [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=CAP+theorem) would be one way to find papers, but actually reading the papers will often cost you money.

Comment: @v1d3rm3 Go to https://www.google.com and search for "data consistency in distributed system". I've never read any of the papers or the books because the subject is kind of way over my pay-grade. I've only ever read tech notes from Oracle, IBM and Nokia-Siemens when I was involved with developing distributed databases for Nokia-Siemens-Networks (now Nokia Networks). I only ever did the low-level networking C code and LDAP parsers. They had experts write solutions for stuff like sharding and clustering. I just wrote code to implement their specs.

Answer (score 20):

#### There are no easy solutions.

Distributed consistency is fundamentally difficult, with some hard limits to what is possible. See the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) and [Fallacies of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing). And doing *anything* in a large and complex system is inherently costly and risky, so your desire of "a few weeks development time" seem incredible optimistic to me. I have worked at companies spending **years** to slowly move from one database architecture to a newer architecture.

If this problem has been created by using ad-hoc development practices, it is unlikely that the problem can be solved without some fundamental changes.

Writing a "checker script" as you mentions might *help*, but it will likely not solve the problem. Any warnings it generates may be ignored, and the script itself may become outdated unless rigorously maintained.

#### Conways Law

My guess is that this is a case of [Conways law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law), i.e. that if your architecture is a mess it is likely because your organization is a mess. A possible approach is the "Inverse Conway maneuver" - I.e. you should change your organization to mirror how you want your architecture to be. If you want consistent data, create a group that has the responsibility to manage data and data consistency, and the power to actually do that. My guess is that the first step such a group would take would be to make all data access go thru a single service/application layer/API, and once that is done, start moving towards using a single database.

Or you could embrace the micro-services philosophy of independent groups developing independent services/applications with separate databases, where interaction between applications are governed by APIs with some type of service and backward compatibility guarantees. This would mean that cross database dependencies are minimized, and that there should be a well defined behavior for any inconsistencies that do occur. But this require some serious thought about where the boundaries should be, and how to handle all the various failure modes.

Of course, suggesting to completely change the way the company works is easier said than done.

Comment: The microservice architecture is good for maintainability and scalability, but it's terrible for consistency - how does microservice A know when microservice B deletes a row that A has a reference to? So B broadcasts a delete event, but messages occasionally don't get delivered. The only answer is to design systems that are fault-tolerant.

Comment: Dealing with message non-delivery (and even failure of a listener while it is processing a message) is easy enough. But guarding against out-of-band failure modes (such as a botched upgrade/migration of the MQ infrastructure) is almost impossible. So you still need fault tolerance.

Comment: I don't think monolithic systems are more fault tolerant. I was only pointing out that switching to microservices is unlikely to make consistency problems go away. I think your edits make that clear too.

Comment: @IanGoldby Then we are in agreement. I did not mean to imply that microservices could *solve* consistency problems, Only that a well designed system could reduce the chance, and mitigate the effects of such problems. I hope the text makes this clear, and apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 7):

You don't! You don't ensure consistency across multiple databases.

If there are multiple technologies, and multiple databases in the conventional sense, then ensuring consistency means designing everything to work together as an integrated whole again.

You might find some technologies simply won't compose into a system because they aren't designed to be composable together in the first place.

Most likely what you'll end up doing by trying to make a single database out of heterogenous technologies, is impairing every possible facility each technology provides to make a database manageable - facilities that have had the world's best minds chiselling away on them for decades - and you'll be tasked with reimplementing all these facilities at the application level. Journalling, transaction management, consistent online backup and recovery, scaling and performance. In reality you won't succeed at this.

As you anticipated, your real option is limited to performing extensive and frequent reconciliation, and resolution of differences as they are found.

Answer (score 7):

> *"I'm not asking for organizational measurements"*

Don't get me wrong, but that sounds pretty **ignorant**. You are simply describing all kind of quality issues in data. Quality issues require a quality control process, and such processes usually require a combination of technical and organizational measures. Moreover, they need to be tailored to the individual case.

Lets look, for example, at the approach you described, with a checker scripts which tags data with labels "Please fix it". That's a technical measure which requires an organizational process in addition: someone who gets informed about these tags and does the fixing. Next step is to think about the **importance** of the data and their consistency:

- is the data consistency so important that someone will be payed to fix the data on a regular basis? For some organizations and systems, "regular" means "within a few hours", for others, it may mean "once every two years".
- maybe it is sufficient to let the one fix the data who tries to use them in some downstream use case, at the time when they stumble over the data?
- or maybe it is sufficient to leave the inconsistency as it is, just display the inconsistency as a warning for the one who is trying to order the pet food for a dog?

When creating applications which work multiple, distributed databases, it is necessary to make the applications robust enough to expect certain inconsistencies and react accordingly. But what "accordingly" means is highly case dependendent, and cannot be answered out of context, without knowing what the data is used for, and wihout knowing the cost/benefit relationship of *"fixing all issues ASAP"* vs *"live with the issues"*.

Let me further mention another well-known general strategy besides your "checker script":

- if you have the same information stored in different places, declare one place as the "leading one", the "single source of truth", and sync the others in a downstream manner.

For example, you may consider to store the information of food being suitable for a certain pet primary by where the food document links to, and sync the `suitableFor...` fields automatically (and only automatically!) from the former information. Or, you may go a step further and remove the `suitableFor...` fields completely from the food documents (this, however, requires you to know all current usages of those fields in your system, and the ability to change those usages). As you see, this may require organizational changes, since the `suitableFor...` may have been maintained by some person X manually beforehand, which now may has to use a different application for maintaining the food - pet links, or maybe has nothing to do here any more, because maintaining the food - pet links was already someone elses job.

So in short, there isn't a "one-size-fits-all" solution to this problem.

When asking for *"technical actions that a motivated dev-team could implement within, very roughly speaking, a few weeks"*, the answer is neither *"no there are no such actions"* nor *"there are these actions..."*. The answer is "it depends heavily on the case if certain technical actions will solve the issues, and it is pointless to think about technical measures without taking their organizational impact into account.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that there are organizational measurements as well to be taken. However, the question is already broad enough (as others have already pointed out) and I even think most organizational matters would be off topic here. Hence, I want them to be excluded here. Thanks nevertheless for your thoughts!

Comment: @cis: well, my point is that it makes not much sense to seek for technical measures by ignoring the organizational aspects and quality requirements. Those things typically go hand-in-hand, and any sensible approach should never ignore this.

Comment: Yes, I agree, you need to consider all aspects in the end. But, again, I think that discussion might be too broad for this site. I made an edit to my answer. Hope that makes it clearer what I'm asking for here.

Comment: "you can't tech your way out of a people problem" +1

Comment: "*sync the fields automatically (and only automatically!) from the former information.*" - depending on the subsystem, this may involve manual steps, and there might be (non-automatic) two-way synchronisation. Granted, you'd likely have two fields in the secondary service, like `true_suitableFor…` and `divergentLocal_suitableFor…`, where the former is always, automatically, immediately synced from the source of truth, and the latter is the value that the service is using internally. That way, you can find and deal with the inconsistency in a single database at least.

Comment: @cis: maybe I wasn't clear enough, so let me say this straight: your idea to ask for purely technical measures, excluding organizational imptact, is IMHO  completely flawed. Seeking technical solutions for organizatioal issues simply doesn't work.

Comment: very well said.

Comment: @Doc Brown Thanks for that clarification. But well, I disagree. Why do have most relational databases things like foreign key constraints, row checks, post update hooks etc for controlling data quality? Or even schemas? You could also argue that these are attempts for solving "organizatioal issues" technically. You could argue that it's an organizational problem if someone tries to put a string into a number column. But schemas and constraints exist in the relational world and they are quite useful. So, it's not too far fetched to seek for solutions for problems on the layer of multiple DBs.

Comment: @cis: technical measures like database constraints can only help to support data quality, in the end, the need to be embedded into organizational processes. But when data already has a low quality, you need an organizational process to curate it first, then establish a combination of technical and/or organizational measures for keeping the achieved level of quality high.  Trying to approach this only on a technical level is a well-know recipe to desaster.

Answer (score 3):

### Distributed redundant data

My approach would be thus (I restrict myself to relational DBMS terms, i.e. "table" would include your MongoDB analog):

- Define, for each table, which of your databases is the "master". Authoritative changes to rows in that table are made in that database only - that particular database is the only "source of truth" for those entities.
- If it makes sense, provide some kind of API to access that table, and/or some kind of pub-sub mechanism (for example, Kafka) for clients to receive upserts. If you find applications that have a copy of that data and are manipulating *that*, then change them to use that API.
- If you absolutely *require* the data to be cached or mirrored somewhere for whatever reason (there are plenty of valid ones, not the least performance in a distributed environment, but sometimes simply the ugly truth of historically grown system) make sure this is clearly documented and implemented in a form that is *not* a "master" database; i.e. the inferiour DB would be receiving updates to that table not via business process, but via separate caching or mirroring approaches (i.e., detect changes on the master and distribute them to the slaves in some fashion that makes sense - maybe on the DB level via a warm/hot standby, or via some pub-sub mechanism like Kafka).
- If switching a slave who is modifying data in their own copy can simply not be changed to calling an API in the master, then invent a new table that reflects "changes to $TABLE" - i.e. if you have a table PEOPLE on your master, then on the slave, when trying to change that table, you would also generate "events" in a second table PEOPLE_EVENTS_IN_SLAVE_APP (or whatever name you come up with). The slave is then the master of *that* table, and the rest of this section applies (those events would be transferred to the master of PEOPLE, integrated, constraints checked and so on and forth - and when due to this the PEOPLE table on the master changes, those changes will be sent back to the slave again as per the next bullet point).
- The mechanism to replicated data from master to slaves for caching purposes should be such that you can do a full transfer with relative ease - i.e., the only manual intervention should be kicking off the process, the rest should be automated.
- Whenever such a mechanism has been created, do a full transfer once. Then, if you notice deviations between master and slave later, figure out what changed the values in the slave DB, and work diligently on reducing these reasons, as far as possible. If it is simply not humanly possible (or not within budget), you can opt to do a force refresh (i.e., full transfer) regularly and fully automated.

### De-normalized data

This, unfortunately, is also simply a truth in real-world distributed systems (or, heck, any kind of single DB if it has grown over sufficiently many decades).

Unfortunately, it is hard to give a generic recommendation here. Obviously, where you can, work on normalizing your data. You write that there are ad-hoc manipulations -> this can often be just fine, depending on the domain, but the database schema should be thus that even with manual intervention, an invalid state simply is not possible to achieve. There is nothing special about this, [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is a more or less solved problem.

For those DBs that are not really as powerful in this specific regard (i.e., MongoDB where you are sure that you cannot use schema fidelity for some reason), maybe the impact is lessened after you have strictly done the previous approach mentioned in this answer, i.e., changed every single entity so that it has a defined, single "master" in your whole distributed system.

Comment: When do you need to opt for a regular force-refresh? Would not making the slave DB readonly be the simpler choice, so that any applications that attempt to write deviant data would get an error straight away (instead of getting their changes silently rolled back later)?

Comment: Yes of course - this is just for cases where for outside reasons this is not possible (say, some application not under your control where it absolutely needs writable access to a table; let's say to update some uncritical time stamp or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with transactional databases using the **two phase commit** by the transaction manager:

- Transactions are prepared on all databases, transferring all data.
- Transaction manager verifies that these transactions are actually prepared and ready to be committed.

Anywhere above this point the manager can easily rollback transactions if some databases experience problems.

- Transaction manager issues commands for all nodes to commit the transactions.

A well designed database is expected to report errors, if any, when preparing the transaction and not during the final commit stage.

- Transaction manager verifies if all transactions are committed. If for some reason commit message failed to reach some nodes (unlikely), it can be re-sent.

If transaction manager crashes itself, it can always query the pending transactions after it recovers and continue from where left.

Comment: Thanks for those thoughts. I'm just wondering: Which transactional manager supports both, let's say, MariaDB and MongoDB?

Comment: Maria is not the problem as it is a real transactional database. Postgresql can also do. You can mix different databases as long as they do support real transactions where you can even have queries and read uncommitted data within the scope of the running transaction. Unfortunately lots on "noSQL" stuff may not.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach of programmatically defining rules and running a checker script is a step in the right direction. However, as you rightly pointed out, relying solely on notifications to responsible individuals may not guarantee consistent data maintenance.

A more technically oriented solution would involve considering data quality tools and techniques. You could explore the use of data quality management software that offers features for data profiling, cleansing, and monitoring. These tools can help you establish and enforce data quality rules, scan for inconsistencies, and trigger alerts or automated actions when issues are detected. By implementing data quality management solutions, you can systematically address data inconsistencies and validation concerns across multiple databases.

Additionally, you might want to investigate the field of Master Data Management. MDM systems are designed to ensure the consistency and reliability of critical data across an organization. While it may take more than a few weeks to implement a full MDM solution, some MDM platforms offer rapid deployment options and can be a valuable long-term investment for maintaining data consistency.

Your quest for a comprehensive, technically-driven solution is not unwarranted, and the right data quality and MDM tools can significantly simplify the process of keeping your data consistent and valid over time. While there might not be a one-size-fits-all "XY" solution as described, researching data quality management and Master Data Management solutions could lead you to the tools and techniques that fit your specific needs.